# ffmpeg auto split into exact timeframes

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to autosplit a video into smaller clips of same length using ffmpeg. I know the command:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:05 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.mp4)
```

But this one splits videos into frames so the time is varying.
I found a command

```
ffmpeg -i "name" -ss 0 -t 5 p1.mp4
ffmpeg -i "name.mp4" -ss 5 -t 5 p2.mp4
ffmpeg -i "name" -ss 10 -t 5 p3.mp4
```

But this would mean i would have to do it manually for whole video. Is there way to automate the process so i can split the video into exact time? Thank you.

I'm using Windows 10 if it makes any difference

Comment: Do you want to split the video into small parts of 5 secs each? without re-rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the first command again, but lose the -map and put -c copy before the output video, it worked on my test video, all videos have the same length except for the last one, but that is probably because the main video is not divisible by the segment time...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -segment_time 00:00:05 -f segment -y -reset_timestamps 1 -c copy "seg_%03d.mp4"
```